# Asana project export via bash / curl / etc example

Tags: bash, curl, export, backup, asana

I'm trying to create a shell script for exporting all projects out of one Asana account.

I got it to work temporary using a huge cookie description in a header, but this stops working when restarting or else of course. I am aiming for an automatic export script for all projects.

Please show me an example code for bash / curl / wget or similar, that **exports a project of an asana account** to a folder. One project export would be good enough here. For example:

- script.sh
- backups  * backup1.csv, backup2.csv, ...
- logfiles * logfile_p1, logfile_p2,   ...

Additions like date, scheduling are no problem. I just need a permanently working link example for exporting a project. Asana offers an export function for this, but i am too low for using it right in a script.

**What i did gets me an http website as saved file:**

```
curl -u <API_KEY>: https://app.asana.com/-/csv?id=<PROJECT_ID> -o <NAME>.csv -L
```

**Further links:**

- https://app.asana.com/-/csv?id=
- http://developer.asana.com/documentation/

Comment: Can you not use a more expressive scripting language like Node, or Python? The primary difficulty isn't in the REST API -- it's that Asana resources are protected by OAuth 2.0, which is a pain to handle in bash+curl etc. (although it can be done, with other shell friends: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244110/use-bash-curl-with-oauth-to-return-google-apps-user-account-date).