# Microsoft OneDrive API InvalidAuthenticationToken CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105

Tags: bash, curl, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have looked at the two similar questions in StackoverFlow and on the web but I still don't understand what I should do.

I want to download a file that is located on OneDrive programmatically using a bash script (with curl).

So I've seen [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/graph_oauth.htm) that I can use the **code flow** to access Microsoft Graph. So I proceeded like that (I inspired myself from the [Jay Lee answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244110/use-bash-curl-with-oauth-to-return-google-apps-user-account-data)):

1- I get the code with this URL 
`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=10c492f9-132a-4079-adae-382dad9d4339&scope=onedrive.readonly&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`

2- Then I swap authorization code for access token with this URL:
`curl -X POST https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf -d "client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}&code=${auth_code}&grant_type=authorization_code" --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

And I store the token and the expire time in a file

3- I made some process to handle the fact that I have to refresh the token (according to the expire time).

4- I use my token to download my file programmatically with Microsoft Graph

`api_data=$(curl https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/B8D9948257F95B84%21104/content -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token")
echo -e "$api_data"`

The problem- When I run the program, I get this:

[image]

How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're authenticating against the wrong endpoint. The `login.live.com` endpoint cannot provide a valid token for Graph. You need to use the [v2 Endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview) for this instead.

Check out [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) for a walkthrough. Given that you're using curl, the pseudo code provided should give you everything you need.